# Display WP content when Ajax initiate modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I tried figuring out how my modal-file is not displaying my WP content and if i try something else, it end up 500 (Internal Server Error), though I figured out already the case for Internal Server Error. Here's the code from my Modal.

```
<?php include '/wp-blog-header.php'; ?>

<?php $postname = new WP_Query([ 'post_type' => 'causes', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'p' => $_POST['key'] ]); ?>
<?php while ( $postname->have_posts() ) : $postname->the_post(); ?>
<div class="uk-modal-dialog">
  <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
  <div class="fetched-data">
    this is modal popup
    <?php echo $post->post_name; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Though if I am doing it in a plain text, it does display the modal.
Here's my Ajax script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.open-modal').on('click', function(){
    var postID = $(this).attr('data-content');

    var modal = UIkit.modal(".uk-modal", {center: true, bgclose: false});
    if ( modal.isActive() ) {
      modal.hide();
    } else {
      modal.show();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/structures/modal/modal-donate.php",
        data: { key : postID },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.uk-modal').html(data);
        }           
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**NOTE**

I update the Modal File to this look:

```
<?php 
  require '../../../../../../wp-load.php';
  require '../../../../../../wp-blog-header.php';

  echo $postKey = $_POST['key'];
  global $post;
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'causes', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'p' => $postKey );
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
?>

<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<div class="uk-modal-dialog">
  <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
  <div class="fetched-data">
    <p>this is modal popup</p>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Though Ajax Error keeps showing in my modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `dataType: "json"` is the cause of my error here, so after I read back again the jQuery Ajax documentation, I see that my case issue is just back to "html" type only. So here's the full solution to my question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.open-modal').on('click', function(){
    var postID = $(this).attr('data-content');

    var modal = UIkit.modal(".uk-modal", {center: true, bgclose: false});
    if ( modal.isActive() ) {
      modal.hide();
    } else {
      modal.show();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        url: "wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/structures/modal/modal-donate.php",
        data: { key : postID },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.uk-modal').html(data);
        }           
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include "wp-load.php" file on top of the page to execute the WordPress function first.

```
include("../../../wp-load.php");
```

And to call "modal-donate.php" file you can set code something like that if you have set script inside PHP file,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>"/inc/structures/modal/modal-donate.php",
        data: { key : postID },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.uk-modal').html(data);
        }           
      });
```

Comment: actually, im initiating Ajax via my `scripts.min.js` to call the Modal "modal-donate.php... though i completely dropped the `500 (Internal Server Error)` though the Ajax Error still appearing with a little delay after the execution of the modal.

Comment: Ok, i found the issue now here... I update the `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "html"` and it works fine now.